# How do I randomize block position with /setblock in Minecraft Bedrock Edition?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I wanted to make an Among Us style map on Minecraft Bedrock Edition, (to play with friends) and I was trying to make the "Eject trash" task and want the dirt block that is placed outside of the window to be placed in a random position, within a 9x9 block radius, but I don't know any command to do this. Is there a way to input coordinates that randomize where is it placed?

Comment: Install WorldEdit on your server and use the //fill command. The vanilla fill command doesn't support percentage selection

Comment: @hfanatic world edit isnt on bedrock

Answer (score 2):

You could summon an armour stand:

```
summon armour_stand dirt_location
```

Then use `/spreadplayers` to randomise its location:

```
spreadplayers ~ ~ 10 11 @e[name=dirt_location]
```

Then use `/execute` to set the block:

```
execute @e[name=dirt_location] ~ ~ ~ setblock ~ ~ ~ dirt
```

And finally, remove the armour stand with:

```
kill @e[name=dirt_location]
```

You will want all those commands chained together with chain command blocks.